# GooglePlaces api to get information about stores iphone application

Tags: iphone, google-maps

In my iPhone application, i want to show nearest stores to given latitude and longitude.

I have used googlePlaces api to get nearby stores to given location coordinates.

But i want to get other information about stores as well like opening and closing time of each store etc.

How can i get that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [PlaceDetails](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceDetails)

Comment: thanks for advice but it doesnot say anything about other information like opening and closing time